# Ubuntu one (application) on ubuntu software center

Tags: 14.04, software-center

I went on the ubuntu software center to get ubuntu one (application), found it and clicked it. Then shows "NOT FOUND   There isn’t a software package called “ubuntuone-control-panel-qt” in your current software sources."

I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu one has ended it no longer exists. I recommend dropbox.
https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx
or you can install dropbox from software center it is already in the repositories.